# How to model attributes dependencies between different classes in UML object diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

In scope of visualizing different parts of the system I would like to exactly show dependency between different attributes.

In my case the use case will be in UI where a User have to to choose Country and based on his selection values for Product have to be updated in corresponding dropdown eg.

Values for Class `Country`:

- `Country1`
- `Country2`
- `Country2`

Values for Class `Product`:

- `Product1` (*available ONLY for* `Country1`)
- `Product2` (*available for* `Country1` AND `Country2`)
- `Product3` (*available ONLY for* `Country2`)
- `Product4` (*available ONLY for* `Country3`)

I've read about derived properties and constraints as it might be my case.
Also some links might be related to the same issue:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/386816/how-to-model-attribute-dependency-inside-one-class-in-uml-class-diagram

But for now I do not have a working solution.

For general purpose I've tried to represent these relationships with abstract Class diagram but it's hard for me to do this with exact values of these Classes within Object diagram

[image: Class diagram]

Comment: In general you don't model these type of runtime configuration values. Your UML model is a class model at design time, not at an object model at runtime. You should however model the configuration class that will contain the different configuration for the different products.

Comment: Your class diagram doesn't seem related to your question.

Comment: Thanks for you answer - I am only starting to getting know UML and all these diagrams.
The point is I would like to have not only abstract visualization but more specific one with values dependencies made clear if possible - in that case in addition to attached Class diagram I suppose I need to create another Object Diagram.

Comment: So what is your real question? How to model the first table (country/product) in UML?

Comment: Yes - exactly! How to model this dependency between actual values Country / Product?

Comment: @FedirKovalenko to use of a dependency between Country and Product is a bad choice,  use a _constraint_

Answer (score 0):

You would likely model that as association class:

[image]

The `CountryProduct` needs to filled with the according information (so it my contain the price which is used for a product in a country).

You "could" model that as constraints on the association between `Product` and `Country` as well. But I'd bet that business will not be happy with that since it sets all in concrete when coding, while business expects quite some flexibility here.

Comment: If I well understand the OP does not ask to know the price of a product depending on the country, but how to model "Product1 (available ONLY for Country1)" etc. How the class-relation does that ? How it blocks the availability of Product1 in all countries except Country1 ?

Comment: @bruno Well, that's what the above is all about. Only for entries in `CountryProduct` there's a validity set. The requirements from the Product-list can easily be fulfilled. The "except" is a requirement you planted here, but is not requested by the OP. However, even that is easily modeled by putting in entries for all countries except the one where you don't want it.

Comment: _The "except" is a requirement you planted here, but is not requested by the OP._ I do not understand, it doesn't come from me, all the question of the OP is about that. `Product1 (available ONLY for Country1), Product2 (available for Country1 AND Country2),  Product3 (available ONLY for Country2), Product4 (available ONLY for Country3)` is in the question or I really need to change my glasses ? ^^

Comment: @bruno Where in the citation is the word `except`? My eyes are old, but my glasses are good.

Comment: for instance _available ONLY for Country1_ is not equals to _unavailable to all except for Country1_ ? I suppose you speak about my original sentence  _blocks the availability of Product1 in all countries except Country1_

Comment: @bruno Ah, cmon. "Only for 1 country" is a SINGLE entry in the association class. "Except" means a relation to all countries except for one. What is your problem? Though this was not required, it's easily possible to do.

Comment: we do not speak about the same thing, since the beginning I speak about _constraint_, I never speak about a relation between Product1 and all Countries except Country1 etc if this is what you understood. Please note also hat the OP was the first to speak about _constraint_

Comment: @bruno Well, even if so, it just takes me to believe that he actually **needs** an association class. Let's call it a day and let the OP decide...

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `Association` between `Product` and `Country`. If you want to capture attributes for each Product-Country-pair, such as the price mentioned by @Thomas, an `AssociationClass` is the natural choice.

In an Object-Diagram Instances of the Association (links) can be shown as lines. You would have lines between Country1 and Product1, and Country2 and Product2 and Product3...
This could be used to illustrate the structure of your system and how it evolves over time. To really define it, other diagrams are better suited.

I don't see, how constraints on the Association can help. Textual Constraints could be on some additional Class `Selection`. The start of the constraint could be: `context Selection: product = product1 implies country in (country1)`. This would not allow to later add new products. And the constraints defined by the Links between countries and products are much more readable.